# Cannot run transcode.c from ffmpeg examples

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, transcoding

Whenever I try to run the ffmpeg example transcode.c I get the following error

```
[libx264 @ 000000c428ef9260] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 000000c428ef9260] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 000000c428ef9260] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 000000c428ef9260] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 000000c428ef9260] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
Cannot open video encoder for stream #0
```

I am running it as C++ code in Visual Studio windows. I had to make some changes to run it as C++. Link for the code here
http://pastebin.com/qAf7sbsp
The output file I am giving is a duplicate of the input file.

Comment: Add an encoding preset like libx264 requests.

Comment: Those messages indicate that you're probably using a really old source.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I am using ffmpeg-2.5.4
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
  libavformat    56. 26.101 / 56. 26.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 13.101 /  5. 13.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

this was latest a week back

Answer (score 0):

you should pass encoder param to avformat_new_stream

```
    encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
    out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, encoder);
```